# How to select and move plenty of files from a folder to another folder in a bucket on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have more than 10,000 files in a folder and i want to select some of these files (around 2,000 of them) and move it to another folder on the same bucket. I have the list of files names to be moved and i'm looking for a way or a script to go through the files and move them to the destination folder. how can i do that easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 does not have a "move" operation. Instead, you can copy the objects to a new location and then delete the original objects.

From [Performing large-scale batch operations on Amazon S3 objects - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops.html):

> You can use **S3 Batch Operations** to perform large-scale batch operations on Amazon S3 objects. S3 Batch Operations can perform a single operation on lists of Amazon S3 objects that you specify.

You can provide the list of files in a CSV file and configure the batch to copy the objects to a new location. However, I'm not sure if you can then delete the list of source files, so it's not really "moving" the objects.

Frankly, the method I use is:

- **Create an Excel spreadsheet** with a list of objects in column A
- Create a formula in column B like: `="aws s3 mv s3://bucket/"&a1"& s3://bucket/destination/"&a1"`
- Then, Fill Down to create the formula in every row
- Finally, copy column B into a text file

Test a couple of lines to make sure it works correctly, then simply run the text file in Shell. It will copy the files across. Not the world's fanciest method, but should work fine for 2000 files!